# How do I set up a user account in Gmail to receive email?

Tags: gmail

I recently set up email with my host. Then I set up a Gmail account to enable people to use their email addresses. Now the people on my team can send emails from their Gmail addresses as `name@domain.com`. But they can not receive email.

How can I set up Gmail so that people can open their accounts and see the emails that are sent to them?

Comment: You want to see email where? Online (on Gmail) or in a mail client like Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

[Configure MX records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140034) in your domain :

When you’re switching to Google Apps and you want to receive emails in Google Mail (Gmail), you’ll need to point your MX records to the Google mail servers.

You modify MX records using the administration tools of your domain host and not the Google Admin panel.

Be aware it may take up to 72 hours before changes are propagated, depending on the TTL that was configured for your MX records.

Comment: I went to https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/problemio.com which is the home for my company's email. But when I went to settings, there was no accounts and import.

Comment: Could you please explain how to navigate to the right plance

Comment: It is this line, right? "Allow users to import mail from Yahoo!, Hotmail, AOL, or other webmail or POP3 accounts"

Comment: that line is for migration of email/contacts. You want them to access emails from another email address?

Comment: You see, I set up the company email with gmail. So instead of name@gmail.com their email would be name at mydomainname.com ...but it would be managed in gmail for business.  Does that make sense?

Comment: did you adjust your MX record? I edited my main answer... above

Comment: @Genadinik You have to do this on the website of the company you registered your domain name with.